# Bisector function returns always same object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to visualize the y-Axis value, but have problems with receiving the index of the data my mouse is hovering. The dateformat of the data is: JJJJ-MM-TT\Thh:mm:ss.ssZ and the objects in data are sorted by date.

```
  d3.json("all.json", function (data) {

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left:0}
var containerWidth = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
var containerHeight = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Only show temperature data
 var temp_data = data.filter(
 function(el)
    { return el.sensor =="Multisensor:sensormultilevel::temperaturesensor:";
    }       
 );


var data_count = temp_data.length;
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).right;
var formatValue = d3.format(",.2f");
var formatTemperature = function(d) { return formatValue(d) + "°"; };


var minDate =  Date.parse(temp_data[0].date);
var maxDate =  Date.parse(temp_data[temp_data.length-1].date);

//Create time scale
var x = d3.time.scale()
                        .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                        .range([0, containerWidth]);

//Create the xAxis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom')
.ticks(d3.time.days, 3)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d.%m'))
    .tickSize(3)
    .tickPadding(8);


var y_max = calcMax(temp_data);
var y_min = calcMin(temp_data);


//Create temp scale
var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([50, y_max + 5])
.range([containerHeight, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.tickSize(3)
.orient('left');


//Add svg Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", containerWidth + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", containerHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom).append('g')
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

//This is the accessor function for the line
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(Date.parse(d.date)); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .interpolate("linear");


//Add line
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(temp_data))
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    ;

//Add xAxis
var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", "xAxis").attr("transform",       "translate(0, " + (containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")").call(xAxis); 

//Add yAxis
var yAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", "yAxis").call(yAxis).append("text")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", 6)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Temperature in Fahrenheit");

   var focus = svgContainer.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .style("display", "none");

   focus.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);

   focus.append("text")
  .attr("x", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em");

   svgContainer.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", containerWidth)
  .attr("height", containerHeight)
  .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);


function mousemove() {
    var x01 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);

    x0 = Date.parse(x01);       

    var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return Date.parse(d.date); }).right;

    var item = data[bisect(temp_data, x0, 1)];
    console.log("item: " + item);

    var i = bisectDate(temp_data, item.date, 1);

    var d0 = temp_data[i - 1];
    var d1 = temp_data[i];

    var d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

    console.log("x0: " + x0 + " i: " + i + " d0: " + d0 + " d1: " + d1 + "y(" + d.value +  "): " + y(d.value));

    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.value) + ", " + y(d.value) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(formatTemperature(d.value));
}

});


function calcMin(d) {
    var min = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {

    var value = d[i].value;
    if ( value <= min ) { min = value; }
}
return min;
}

function calcMax(d) {
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {

    var value = d[i].value;
    if ( value >= max ) { max = value; }
}
return max;
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you're comparing `Date` objects and strings. You need to parse the strings into `Date` objects for this to work.

Comment: Not sure what to parse. I create a new Date from x0 and return a new Date in the bisctor function (see updated code). But still no different results.

Comment: You're not parsing it, you're just constructing a `Date` object (which may or may not work, depending on the browser). How are you processing those dates in the first place for the chart?

Comment: I added new code to let you see, that I actually don't process the dates beforehand. How should I parse the Dates?

Comment: I inserted my whole code now. I could solve the problem with getting the right item. But now the function x(d.value) return always a strange value: Around -714889.1327115165 and it changes by moving the mouse, but only in the last 3 digits...

Comment: You can find the documentation on parsing dates with D3 [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).